# <VirtualizedList> has duplicate key, but it shouldn't

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using  in the following way:

```
<VirtualizedList
  onEndReachedThreshold={DEFAULT_THRESHOLD_VALUE}
  getItem={(data, index) => data[index]}
  getItemCount={(data) => data.length}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id + index}
  {...props}
  data={listData}
  onEndReached={getNextPageData}
  ListFooterComponent={footerComponentJsx}
/>
```

As you can see, for `keyExtractor` prop, I'm using the index as well as `item.id`, so I don't think I should get any duplicate keys. Yet, I get this error:

```
 ERROR  Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Can someone give me some insights on why this is happening and how to remedy this?

Comment: Can you log the `id`s or is the data reported?

Comment: If you just pass the item.id as the keyExtractor does it still throw the error?

Comment: @DanielJ Yes, it does.

Comment: @OFRBG I don't know what you mean by "is data reported", but I know there are duplicates in it for this particular component. What I'm wondering is why it's erroring out even with the index added. Shouldn't index be different for each item, regardless of whether they're duplicates?

Comment: Never work an array index into your keys. If the item ids are unique, use those, and only those. Consider: id 10 and index 1, and id 1 and index 10, yield the same compound key, so by adding the index you took a value that uniquely identifies items, and explicitly turned those into guaranteed collisions: just use `item.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there are maybe the same keys for an item in your:

```
 keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id + index}
```

So be clear about item.id+index is not the same for two item.

So do one thing give a unique id for each item in item.id and then use it as below:

```
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's worked for me.
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}

Answer (score 0):

You can just add random number in it.

If you are sure that you have id in your item.

```
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${Number(item.id) + Number(index)}`}
```

If you are not sure that you have id in your item.

```
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${Math.random() + Number(index)}`}
```